# Como usar a função strip() junto a uma lista ou tupla no python?

Tags: python-3.x

Estou criando um script e em um trecho eu crio uma lista e em seguida utilizo a função strip() junto ao upper() dentro do input v1, mas na hora de chamar o script e executar ele não retorna nada, como posso resolver isso?

```
....
    opcao_sim = ('SIM','YES')
    opcao_nao = ('NÃO','NO')
    v1 = str(input('Deseja criar um repositorio? n[s]: ')).strip().upper()[0]
    if v1 in op_sim:
            print('ok! bons estudos XD')
            sys.exit(0)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Entendi meu proprio erro, caso alguém estaja com essa mesma duvida.

```
  sim = ('S','Y')
    nao = ('N')
    v1 = str(input('Digite sim ou não ')).strip()[0].upper()
    if v1 in sim:
            print('você digitou sim ')
    elif v1 in nao:
            print('Você digitou não ')
```

dentro da lista vc tem que colocar a letra que você quer pegar, foi um erro bem bobo.. e se caso vc for utilizar o .upper() coloque a letra em maiúscula ou se for .lower() coloque em minuscula

lembrando que o `[0]` significa que vc quer a primeira letra, ja que o python começa a contar do 0

Answer (score 0):

Teu código está validando com **op_sim**, mas creio que seja **opcao_sim**.

Independente disto você está pegando o primeiro caractere da resposta ("S", "Y" etc) e procurando por ela dentro da tupla `("SIM", "YES")`. A solução mais simples é substituir a tupla por uma *string*, algo como `opcao_sim="SY"`e aí a validação funcionará corretamente.

Dica, fica melhor usar `v1=str(input("...")).strip()[0].upper()` se você só precisa do primeiro caractere da resposta.